# Cannot parse the string in the POST request in Express Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, middleware

I want to create a simple API with a post method in which the string will be sent as a request.On debugging I found that that the string could not be parsed on logging it was showing *undefined*

1. I have tried `app.use(express.json());`
2. Also tried middleware functions but it didn't work.

INDEX.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const env = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//importing the express module
const app  = express();
//creating the app



env.config();
app.use(bodyParser());

//get request for the first page which is set to be a default
app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
     res.send('welcome to the first page');
     console.log(`welcome to the ecommerce site which is oon the ip and port np ${process.env.PORT }`);
});

app.post('/data',(request,response,next)=>{
    response.status(200).json({message:request.body});
    console.log(response.body);
})

//creating an which listens on port 4000
app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`application running at the port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

on posting XYZ or 'XYZ ' or "XYZ" it is printing at localhost:4000/data

```
{
    "message": {}
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation more carefully. You made a typo. It's `express.json()` not `express.json`. (or `bodyParser.json()` not `bodyParser()`)

Comment: Re edit: `bodyParser()` is still wrong … and why are you trying to use a JSON body parser if you aren't POSTing a body formatted as JSON?

Comment: problems fixed i should have passed a json resquest if using express.json